# How do I determine if an item in a array begins with a specific letter

Tags: arrays, sorting, startswith

I've got a simple java assignment. I need to list all the names of the pupils whose names start with the letter "P" (the pupils names are in an array called names).I have tried using if(names[m].startsWith("P")); but I haven't got it to work yet.Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try `if(names[m][0] == 'P')`

Comment: Your `startsWith` solution looks good to me. But I wonder about that semicolon. It shouldn't be there, and perhaps that is what is killing your code.

Comment: That was what the problem was removed it and voila.But I'm not sure how to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `charAt(int index)` String method. The `if`–statement would look like:

```
...
if(names[m].charAt(0) == 'P') 
...
```